# Service Discovery In Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, service-discovery

I am running two services inside of a small cluster for testing purposes. I have an nginx ingress controller, and then Service A which can be curl'ed directly, and then service B which is called from Service A.

I am able to get the call and communication from ingress-> A -> B working properly, if in service A when looking up B, I make an http call to B as follows: http://{ServiceB.serviceName}/... This does not required me to specify a port so long as the external port for Service B is defined on port 80 in its service definition.

However if I change the port of the service definition for Service B from 80 to anything else, in order to use it in service A, I now have to change the url which I use to call service B to http://{Serviceb.serviceName}:{Serviceb.portNumber}/. Basically, I have to add the port number now as well when looking it up. This requires that in Service A, now i have to know not only the name of Service B, as it is defined in the service definition of Service B, but now I have to know also the port as well.

Is there a better way of doing this, or is this currently the only approach ?

Answer (score 2):

> However if I change the port of the service definition for Service B from 80 to anything else

Well, given that each `Service` has its own ClusterIP and therefore its own non-conflicting port, there's no immediate reason one would change a `Service` port -- one would change the `Pod` port to which the `Service` port points. Beyond that, if the `Service` port is consuming a `targetPort: some-name` rather than `targetPort: 1234`, then one would be further exempted from changing the `Service` port, because the `Pod` could just change the `containerPort` of the *named* `Pod` port and downstream things are none the wiser.

That said, if it really is important to change the numeric port of the `Service`, and those ports are *named* correctly, then you can take advantage of the [SRV record support](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#srv-records) provided by `kube-dns` to decouple the app from a hard-coded port number. However, using a `SRV` record makes building the URL a three-step process (lookup records, assemble URL, request URL), which introduces more application code as well as more opportunities for failure.

Comment: The service definition has an external port and target port defined. On service B, as long as the external port is defined as 80, regardless of what the pod port that its points to is, I can get to it from Service A, by just using a url such as http:///{ServiceB.serviceName}. However, if i change the external port of Service B to anything else, I must now include that in the call to Service B from Service A as such http://{ServiceB.serviceName}:{ServiceB.externalPort}. So how do you lookup the url/port of Service B from Service A dynamically and without hardcoding it in config before startup ?

Comment: You'll forgive me if it appears that you literally copied and pasted your question as a comment. Can you distill your question to the exact part of my answer you don't understand?

Comment: Matthew, sorry if it seemed like that, I was trying to reiterate my question, because your response didnt really answer what i was asking. I seemed to have found the answer, which is that the service port will be defaulted to port 80 in a call from Service A -> B, if the calling service does not specify a port explicitly. Thus if my Service B target port is defined on port 80, I do not need to specificy a port when calling B from A, however, if service B's target port is defined on any port other than 80, then it must be specified on the call from Service A -> B, otherwise it will not resolve.